# Argparse: how can I suppress the list of choices for "invalid choice" error?

Tags: python, argparse

How can I suppress or customize the argparse error message when a user passes in an argument outside of the specified choices?

I'm writing a script that requires the user to pass in a number (int) when they execute the program, which I've defined using the `choices` argument.  I understand how to use the `metavar` argument to customize the `--help` text, but when the user passes in a value outside the range, the error field dumps every possible value from the range - not good for a large range!

Here's the code for an example script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--ID",
    type=int,
    choices=range(1, 10),
    required=True,
    help="My helpful help text.",
    metavar="",
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And here's the output:

```
$ python3 foo.py --ID 12
usage: foo.py [-h] --ID 
foo.py: error: argument --ID: invalid choice: 12 (choose from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

In my actual script, I'd have `choices=range(1,1000000)`.  This would not lead to fun error messages if the user enters a number outside that range as they'd be presented with a dump of a million (minus 1) numbers to choose from!

How can I get the error message to read as something more friendly like:

```
$ python3 foo.py --ID 12
    usage: foo.py [-h] --ID 
    foo.py: error: argument --ID: invalid choice: 12 (choose from {1, 9})
```

Comment: You could try setting the `metavar`.  Problems with long choices lists have been discussed in the bug/issues, but I don't think we made any changes.  Another option is to use `type` instead of `choices` to test the input.  Both `type` and `choices` are tested about the same time in the parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the bug/issues.  Can you be more specific with the other half of the comment? I did set the `metavar` so that it suppresses the range when the user passes the help flag.  I'm using `type` already, too, to ensure the input is an `int`.  What's your suggestion for using it differently, please?

Comment: OK, `metavar` affects the `help`, but not the error.  I vaguely recall that being in issue in previous discussions.  `type` can be any function that takes a string, and returns something else (like an integer), or raises an error.  It should be documented.  Raising `argparse.ArgumentTypeError('you custom error message')` is an alternative to the standard `TypeError` or `ValueError`.

Comment: For reference this is [python issue 16418](https://bugs.python.org/issue16418)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a dedicated `Action`:

```py
import argparse

class MyIntRange(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_steing=None):
        if values not in range(1,10):
            parser.exit(1, message=" should be in {1,10}")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--ID",
    type=int,
    action=MyIntRange,
    required=True,
    help="My helpful help text.",
    metavar="",
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```